# how to get the supported instances in an availbility zone in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find all the the supported instances in a particular availability zone using an API.

I have the list in web page like 
*https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/instance-types-az.html*

I want this through API

Comment: The link you've included here implies you're looking for Sagemaker instance types available in a particular AZ - did you end up finding those? or were you just after EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DescribeInstanceTypeOfferings - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypeOfferings.html):

> Returns a list of all instance types offered. The results can be filtered by location (Region or Availability Zone). If no location is specified, the instance types offered in the current Region are returned.

Here is some sample Python code to show instance types in a specific AZ:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instance_type_offerings(LocationType='availability-zone',Filters=[{'Name': 'location', 'Values':['ap-southeast-2a']}])

for offering in response['InstanceTypeOfferings']:
    print(offering['InstanceType'])
```